# How to pass data to custom workflow from CRM advanced find screen

Tags: dynamics-crm, workflow, crm, advanced-search

There is a possibility to call an on-demand workflow from CRM advanced find screen. 
To initiate a workflow, user needs to select records first.

How to pass the selected data to the custom workflow?

e.g.
[image]

Comment: did you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you run Workflow with trigger such as Create or Record or Update of Record or Record assigned or so on i.e automatic trigger, Workflow Activity will have Input Parameter as Target i.e context of Record from which workflow is triggered. In Target you can find info such as record Id, Fields and so on.

But when you run OnDemand workflow, Workflow Activity will not contain Input parameter and hence details such as field and so on from which record it is fired will not be available.
You will only receive few info such as Record Id, Record Logical Name but not field detials.

You will need to Retreive Record with Given Record ID and Record Logical Name

```
IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


Entity abc= service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet("colum1", "field2", "field3", "field4"));
```

Here is the link which explains all in [Details](http://toplinestrategies.com/blogs/crm/workflow-context-target-entity-when-manually-running-workflows)